# No Internet without opening FortiClient

Tags: networking, vpn, network-bridge, nat

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 inside Virtual box with network adapter attached to NAT:

[image]

I installed FortiClient 6.4.8.1056. I can no longer access internet without opening a VPN on FortiClient nor use a Bridge adapter.

How to fix, what to diagnose?

Following suggestion from @raj:

```
ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:bd:ac:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 82233sec preferred_lft 82233sec
    inet6 fe80::c967:fd79:74ee:2f6b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
netstat -r -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp0s3
ping 10.0.2.2
PING 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.302 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.247 ms
```

Diagnostics after restoring FortiClient - independent Internet connection:

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  1.055 ms  0.923 ms  0.841 ms
 2  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  4.798 ms  4.721 ms  4.646 ms

ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.74.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arn09s23-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from arn09s23-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.78): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=13.8 ms

cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search eef.rtu.lv

resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
lines 6-28
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (enp0s3)
      Current Scopes: DNS         
DefaultRoute setting: yes         
       LLMNR setting: yes         
MulticastDNS setting: no          
  DNSOverTLS setting: no          
      DNSSEC setting: no          
    DNSSEC supported: no          
  Current DNS Server: 85.254.225.5
         DNS Servers: 10.151.34.1 
                      85.254.225.5
                      192.168.1.1 
          DNS Domain: ~.          
                      eef.rtu.lv  
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 6-48/48 (END)
```

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask the people that make FortiClient.

Comment: A few hints how to diagnose - as always with network problems: display your network settings (`ip addr show`) and routing table (`netstat -r -n`). Check what is your IP address and if you have a default gateway on your network (one that is assigned to network `0.0.0.0` in netstat output). If no gateway, there's an obvious problem. If gateway exists, check if it's pingable. What next depends on what information you get here.

Comment: @raj I added this diagnostic info to the question.

Comment: Looks correct. There is a default gateway, and you can ping the gateway. Theoretically should work. Try to ping `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS server). Does it work? Does ping to `google.com` work? Do you have "traceroute" installed? If yes, then traceroute to any of these addresses might help. Also check your DNS settings - the contents of file `/etc/resolv.conf` and output of `resolvectl status`.

Comment: @raj, my FortiClient - independent connection has been restored without any intervention from my part. I supplemented my question with all healthy diagnostic output following your last suggestion for future reference - I will observe if this problem recurs.